# Get cURL POST value from different SELECTs

Tags: php, curl, post, drupal-7

I have a PHP cURL script which uploads content to a Drupal 7 website. I use an `<input>`'s `name` and send the value with a POST request. I have stumbled upon a select tag which, unfortunately, has another select connected to it. Both `<select>`s options end up to a `type="hidden"` `<input>`, where the POST request gets the values from.

My code:

```
// first select
<select id="edit-kat-0" name="kat_epi[und][sel][0]" class="form-select">
    <option value="6080">
    // ...
</select>

// second select
<select id="edit-kat-1" name="field_kat_epi[und][sel][1]" class="form-select">
    <option value="7090">
    // ...
</select>

// hidden input is used to send data
<input type="hidden" name="kat_epix[und][hsid]" value="59a7b06e12df0" />
```

The cURL Request command is:

```
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $postdata = array(  
                "title_field[und][0][value]"=>"emporio",
                "kat_epix[und][hsid]"=>"6863",
                "op"=>"Αποθήκευση",
                     );
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    $result=curl_exec($crl);
```

I have used the hidden `<input>` to submit forms with values from the first `<select>`, but I don't know how the values from both `<select>` elements merge.

I have tried to check the value with JavaScript, but Drupal encodes it, making it impossible to know. I have tried a few obvious solutions, like "6080+7090" or "6080&7090" with no luck. Does anyone know how Drupal 7 merges `<select>` elements' values?

Comment: Could you share with us the cURL request command you are using? Also, have you tried already using a linter on your HTML code? I had to correct a couple of spaces already, when editing your post. I hope these were unrelated typos, otherwise, these could affect your result.

Comment: curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
$result=curl_exec($crl); Is this what you want?I have already posted content successfully,just not able to specify sub-categories from the second select

Comment: Yes. I have added this to your question.

Comment: How does the `<input>` get the data from the `<select>`? In your `curl` request, I can see that you are setting data for the `<input>`, but what is the "title_field"?

Comment: In the drupal form there is an add option wich adds all the selected categories and sub-categories to a table and inside the <input> so its done with javascript.Drupal adds 5 large js files wich makes it dificult to locate something specific."title_field" is just another of the form's input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a lot of effort but I finally managed to work this out on my own. The connected SELECTs is a feature of the drupal Hierarchical Select module.This module refreshes the page when a sub-menu element is chosen.This way the SELECTs use a POST request seperatly from all the other fields.

What I did was make cURL call for the hierarchical SELECTs and then one for the rest of the fields.Firefox's network console helps a lot cause you can see all the POST requests and their parameters.